# Spring Boot Scopes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do something similar to the following.  I want to be able to set infoVar in myController and get it in MyResponseEntityExceptionHandler.  I have tried setting the correct scope (i think Request) but I keep getting errors similar to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Controller

```
@RestController()
public class myController() {
  @Autowired private InfoVar infoVar;

  @PostMapping(path = "/stuff")
  public @ResponseBody sutff getStuff(@RequestBody String string)   throws Exception {
    infoVar.setVar("Test123");
    return stuff;
  }
}
```

error handling

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class MyResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired private InfoVar infoVar

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleStuff(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        infoVar.getVar();
        return stuff;
    }
}
```

infoVar

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class InfoVar{
    private String infoVar;
getter and setter for infovar
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the `@RestController` annotation on the handler? I assume you also need to remove the `final` modifier from the method.

Comment: Even if i remove @RestController and final it is still not working.

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-scope.html ("JSR 330 Provider" + links other aproaches) and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#1-request-scope  (uses `@RequestScope` + named bean)

Comment: Hello,  I had tried both of these, but without any success.  I think it is possibly because ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  is outside of the proxying that occurs for beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did come up with an solution but I am not in love with it.  I feel that there should be a way to do this with beans instead of adding to the WebRequest.

Controller

```
@RestController()
public class MyController() {

  @PostMapping(path = "/stuff")
  public @ResponseBody sutff getStuff(@RequestBody String string)   throws Exception {
    InfoVar infoVar = new InfoVar();
    infoVar.setVar("Test123");
    webRequest.setAttribute("infoVar", infoVar, WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    return stuff;
  }
}
```

Error Handling

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleStuff(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        InfoVar infoVar = (InfoVar) request.getAttribute("infoVar", WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        infoVar.getVar();
        return stuff;
    }
}
```

InfoVar

```
public class InfoVar{
    private String var;
getter and setter for var
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Registering a RequestContextListener listener in web.xml file.

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hello, I had already tried doing this, without any luck.  Any other ideas?  Also I tried doing it a little bit differently.  In an @Configuration class I created a public RequestContextListener requestContextListener that returned a new RequestContextListener.

Comment: I also tired @WebListener public class MyRequestContextListener extends RequestContextListener {}